# Best practice to create a s3 bucket in a particular account and put object inside it using JAVA?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am doing a project where I have to measure reliability of a service. I have a Producer/Consumer setup to do that. In my consumer side I am receiving events and each event has a unique eventID. As I have all the eventID's for the events which are published by the producer. My approach is to write all the eventID's for the events received at consumer side and write it to a s3 bucket. I found this example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpJava.html) but I have few doubts so here are my questions:

1- How does my java code will know in which AWS account it needs to create a s3 Bucket?

2- I want to write data for a day and save it everyday, so how to do that?

Let me know if you need any other information from my side?

Comment: Do you have *any* experience with AWS? Why create a bucket each day, why not just save every day using different keys?

Comment: *I found few examples*: where? Have you read the **official** documentation? Have you tried anything? Where is the code you tried?

Comment: I am very new to this. Yes we can use the same bucket every time. Updated the question.

Comment: If you're very new to this, you absolutely need to read the official documentation. All of it. Not just the part about a Java example. You need to understand the **concepts** before using the API.

Comment: How does my java code will know in which AWS account it needs to create a s3 Bucket? Bcz of this I am not able to write any code and try it out

Comment: I checked official documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/gsg/PuttingAnObjectInABucket.html but there they are explaining how to do this using AWS console.

Comment: Again, read the documentation. The example shows (first line of code in the main method) the usage of `new ProfileCredentialsProvider()`. Reading the javadoc (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/profile/ProfileCredentialsProvider.html) of this class explains what it does, and where to find the account credentials). It also links to this page of the documentation (the same documentation you linked): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html. So, again, read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> 1- How does my java code will know in which AWS account it needs to create a s3 Bucket?

Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentialsProvider.html) and see the implementation classes. They all provide different options how the account credentials can be specified.

The ProfileCredentialsProvider will use the profile configuation in `~/.aws/credentials` file

> 2- I want to write data for a day and save it everyday, so how to do that?

I am not sure what you want from the description, here I will assume you want to gather events for a whole day and write the whole set into the S3 bucket (do not create butckets dynamically, number of buckets is limited)

you cannot update an S3 object. So using pure S3 you could e. g. create a folder (s3 key prefix) for each day and and store each event as an object

If you want to have an aggregated list for each day, you will need to store data somewhere else for the day (e. g. DynamoDB, CloudWatch,..) and export logs into  the S3 object daily (e. g. for DynamoDB you could create a Data Pipeline or a Lambda function to export data into an S3 bucket)

Comment: Your understanding is absolutely correct. I am able to create a S3 bucket inside my AWS account. Yes we can't update a s3Object so in that case I am thinking to write data for whole day into file and and when date changes we can put that object to s3.